# Caching the response to a POST request made to a Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have built a GraphQL API on top of Firebase. The API makes use of a Cloud Function connected to Firebase Hosting in order to handle requests.

My purpose is to cache the response for requests sent to the GraphQL API.

An ExpressJS middleware is configured as follows:

```
function setCacheHeaders(req, res, next) {
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
    return next();
}
```

If I send a GET request to the API, I see it hitting the CDN:

```
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1
X-Served-By: cache-lhr6343-LHR
```

However, when I send a POST request (which is the usual manner to interact with a GraphQL endpoint, even if it is a read only operation) I notice that no requests are hitting the cache. However, the response includes the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 311
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2017 05:41:02 GMT
Server: nginx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Cookie
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Served-By: cache-lcy1133-LCY
X-Timer: S1501134062.745716,VS0,VE640
cache-control: public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600
function-execution-id: xg0qjlghrtrv
x-cloud-trace-context: 02434a5f73159e24d949e74026bb8843, 02434a5f73159e24d949e74026bb8843
x-powered-by: Express
```

Is it not possible to cache the response to a POST request with Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. POST is not idempotent, and as you don't get the access to Fastly (Firebase Hosting CDN provider) varnish rules, you cannot even "hack" to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting does not cache POST responses.

I'm not a GraphQL expert, but as far as I can see they allow the [GET verb for non-mutating requests](http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#http-methods-headers-and-body). While it would require you to change your code, it would allow you to cache the response.